# Pandas dot product returns "ValueError: matrices are not aligned" although there is no shape issue. Why?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to multiply a square matrix by itself.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C1':[0, 0, 0.7],  
                   'C2':[0.5, 0, 0],
                    'C3':[0.7, 0.3, 0]
                   }
                 )
```

Trying to do dot product:

```
df2.dot(df2)
```

The outcome should be

```
0.49  0.00  0.15
0.21  0.00  0.00
0.00  0.35  0.49
```

However, I got the following error.

```
ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

There should not be a value error since there is no issue with the dimensions.
What is the problem?

**PS:** df2.multiply(df2) is NOT the solution since it's an element-wise multiplication.

**PS2:** I am looking for a method that will give the same result as the "mmul" function in Excel.

Comment: It's a square matrix (3x3) @tkausl

Comment: Sorry, I misread that. Now its clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`DataFrame.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html)

> The column names of DataFrame and the index of other must contain the same values, as they will be aligned prior to the multiplication.

[image]

you can use numpy array instead

```py
out = df2.dot(df2.values)
```

```
print(out)

      0     1     2
0  0.49  0.00  0.15
1  0.21  0.00  0.00
2  0.00  0.35  0.49
```

Comment: it worked after making the indexes same. However, the output seem wrong. If you can edit it, I will approve your answer.

Comment: @uguros Why the answer is wrong. The output is correct with matrix dot.

Comment: I realized there was a difference between the post and my working copy. Your output is correct, it's my mistake. I will approve your answer. Thanks.